# Android save camera's photo into internal memory

Tags: android, camera

I am new to this site and android. how to save the camera's picture into specific folder and save the picture's name into sqlite databse also.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 //  setContentView(R.layout.camera);
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);  
    File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  "Pic.jpg");
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
            Uri.fromFile(photo));
    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);

    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);  
    onActivityResult(1337, 0, cameraIntent);

}



protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {

    }
```

I opened camera activity. How to get the picture name & save it to particular location?

please help me on this.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm calling camera

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

and saving to sd card like this

```
final ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
img.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(100, 100));
image2 = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
img.setImageBitmap(image2);
String incident_ID = IncidentFormActivity.incident_id;
//l2.addView(img);
    imagepath="/sdcard/RDMS/"+incident_ID+ x + ".png";
File file = new File(imagepath);
try {
bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap( image2,400, 300, true);
file.createNewFile();
FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
bm.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 90, ostream);
ostream.close(); 
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"yourfirst  error message is "
+ e.toString(), 1000).show();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to change the line

```
 if (resultCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
```

to

```
 if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already saving the picture. You provided the location in MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT.

[Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)

Doing a DB you will have to have a look at this [link](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBcQFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html&ei=Y5E6TuHGMNK4hAecrO2jBQ&usg=AFQjCNF8aHy__4EKyivNW9vK1dQKVVb5ag) is a little bit to much to explain

Comment: I want to store specific directory.How can i do .please help